# SQL query, SELECT not in more than 2 records on other table join

Tags: mysql

so i have this two table:
1. private_information

```
| account_no | name   | adrress   |
-----------------------------------
| 123        | andrew | alberque  |
| 234        | melissa| california|
| 456        | matthew| newark    |
```

and then the 2nd table is transaction:

```
| account_no | transaction_num   |
----------------------------------
| 123        | 989890808         |
| 123        | 234247827         |
| 123        | 123621472         |
| 123        | 457465745         |
| 234        | 435446545         |
```

so i want to make this select condition:

```
SELECT * 
From private_information a 
JOIN transaction b ON a.account_no=b.account_no 
WHERE ( <= 2 records in transation table)
```

the account number should not be more than 2 records of transaction number, so `account _no = 123` should not show.

Comment: Which are you using, SQL-Server or MySQL? Don't use inappropriate tags.

Comment: my sql, sorry. mybad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a join with a subquery that counts the number of transactions for each account.

```
SELECT p.*, t1.*
FROM private_information AS p
JOIN transaction AS t1 ON p.account_no = t1.account_no
JOIN (SELECT account_no
      FROM transaction
      GROUP BY account_no
      HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2) AS t2 ON p.account_no = t2.account_no
```

Comment: this serve me well, thanks. one more thing. i wanted to just show 1 row of record of the latest transaction (desc number transaction)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1

Comment: Replace `transaction` in the first join with a subquery that finds the most recent transaction, using one of the methods in that question.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go

```
SELECT * 
FROM private_information a JOIN 
    ( SELECT count(account_no) as counted, 
      account_no 
      FROM transaction 
      HAVING counted <= 2 
      GROUP BY account_no ) b 
ON a.account_no = b.account_no
```

Comment: You can't use `COUNT()` in the `WHERE` clause, it should be in `HAVING`.

Comment: And `< 2` should be `<= 2`.

Comment: You still didn't fix `WHERE` -> `HAVING`

Comment: but i change to `count(account_no)` , better to use where than having

Comment: You can't use `COUNT()` in the `WHERE` clause. Try it and see.

Comment: BTW, you should use ANSI JOIN syntax, not implicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select AA.account_no, AA.name, AA.adrress, CC.transaction_num from 
    (
        select account_no, name, adrress from private_information 
    ) AA inner join
    ( select count(*) as cc, account_no from transation group by account_no having cc <= 2 
    ) BB ON BB.account_no = AA.account_no inner join 
    (
      select account_no, transaction_num from transaction
    ) CC ON CC.account_no = AA.account_no
```

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`. Otherwise you'll still get a row for the accounts that don't match.

Comment: This doesn't return any of the transaction information, it just returns the number of transactions.